# Canvas wont work

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var ball = function() {

this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
this.xSpeed = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
this.ySpeed = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

};


  var balls =[];

for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {

balls[i] = new ball();

}



  function draw() {
 for( i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {

var ball = balls[i]

ctx.beginPath()

if(ball.x < 0 || ball.x > 400) {

ball.xSpeed = -ball.xSpeed;
}

if(ball.y < 0 || ball.y > 400 ) {

ball.ySpeed = -ball.ySpeed;
}

ball.x += ball.xSpeed;

ball.y += ball.ySpeed;

ctx.arc(ball.x , ball.y , 2 , 0 , Math.PI * 2 , false);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fill();
}
}

  function bounce() {

setInterval(draw , 10);

}
```

It should draw more than one ball but it's not drawing any. please help. I can provide html if needed. i have this issue right now. Please help me right now. i It's not drawing any balls. This is unlucky

Answer (score 0):

Call your draw function.
Add: `bounce();` at the bottom.